# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Highcharts.maps')

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts, highmaps

I'm using javascript application including highcharts('Map') at heroku.

Below codes work fine(display map) at http://localhost:3000 , buy didn't work in heroku with same code.
I checked this error in safari.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {

    var mapData = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['custom/world']);
    $('#container_map').highcharts('Map', {
        series : [{
            name: 'Countries',
            mapData: mapData,
            color: '#E0E0E0',
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }, {
            type: 'mapbubble',
            mapData: mapData,
            name: 'Population 2013',
            joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
            minSize: 4,
            maxSize: '12%',
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.z} thousands'
            }
        }]
    });
  });
</script>   

<div id="container_map" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

error code is

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Highcharts.maps')
(anonymous function) ancient-retreat-xxxxx.herokuapp.com
fire - application-71e7db665fe5c7b55d9c6578db1369315ba029918aa95339a81fe6daa4ed7a5e.js:3144
fireWith - application-71e7db665fe5c7b55d9c6578db1369315ba029918aa95339a81fe6daa4ed7a5e.js:3256
ready - application-71e7db665fe5c7b55d9c6578db1369315ba029918aa95339a81fe6daa4ed7a5e.js:3468
completed - application-71e7db665fe5c7b55d9c6578db1369315ba029918aa95339a81fe6daa4ed7a5e.js:3499
```

I have no idea what is causing it or what it even means.

【loaded js in localhost】 
[image]

【loaded js in heroku】
[image]

Comment: Check your network tab in your developer tools.  Did all your scripts load?  My guess is http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js didn't load.

Comment: As you expected, custom/world didn't load. Could you tell me what should I do to load this js?

I edited to upload screenshot (network tab in developer tool, 1st is localhost, 2nd is heroku)

Comment: Try changing the files that aren't loading to https from http.

Comment: up-voted. this solution works well.